# tricky bitset application,error in output

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

I wrote some code that required to calculate the number of set bits in a number as large as 10^19.As i am using c++, i used unsigned long long int to store the number.I wrote two versions for it,one using bitset and one without it.

```
    unsigned long long int b;
    cin>>b;
    int cnt=0;
    while(b){
        if(b&1)cnt++;
        b>>=1;
    }
```

The code above gives correct results.However the following code using bitset gives incorrect results.Though it seems that it should work in exactly the same fashion.

```
    unsigned long long int b;
    cin>>b;
    bitset<64>foo(b);
    int cnt=foo.count();
```

Note that the unsigned long long int will fit in 64 bits, as 10^19<2^64.Some extra detail: So that the question text doesnt get ugly, I am adding the complete code as an ideone link, note lines 51 to 57 http://ideone.com/4Yamhz

Comment: Do you have an input number with which this problem can be reproduced?

Comment: Thats the problem, I dont have it. :(

Comment: Then there is no problem.

Comment: So maybe this is one of the hard to explain funny behaviour of the language/compiler?

Comment: There is nothing to explain unless you can show there is a problem with this particular piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/bitset/,

the constructor of bitset in C++98 admits unsigned long. C++11 instead admits unsigned long long. Truncation maybe? You don't mention the compiler you use, so there you go...

Comment: btw, did you check compiler warnings to verify the above?

Comment: i am using gnu c++ 4.3.2, but this pretty much answers i guess

Comment: Then no C++11 support. Did you check warnings of implicit conversion at the constructor?

Comment: The compiler doesnt give any warnings.